# Is there an FFmpeg parameter to force infinite loop during playback?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there an FFmpeg parameter to force infinite loop during playback? Please note I am not referring to loop the input file.

So basically the input file is e.g. 4 seconds but I want the output file to loop infinitely (or e.g. 100 times) these 4 seconds without actually creating a 400 second file. The file size should be of the size of the 4 seconds but it will play 100 times.

I am looking for something like an internal MP4 loop flag to force the player to loop (I appreciate the player has its own looping settings).

Comment: For mp4 there is no looping setting, for animated gif, webp and maybe other animated images you can use -loop 0 for infinite looping.

Comment: Ups, maybe it's this: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/repeat-loop-input-video-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the output container support.

The most well-known format that supports it is GIF. Looking at the FFmpeg formats documentation shows that GIF, APNG and AVIF support it.

AVIF is based on MPEG-4/ISOBMFF, but FFmpeg parameters for the MP4 container do not include any loop parameter.

```
ffmpeg -ss 5.5 -t 1.9 -i pew-pew.mp4 -c:v libsvtav1 -loop 0 pew-pew-short.avif
```

I couldn't find any video format that supports loop and preserves the audio track.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html